# Remove multiple selected items from a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-actionmode

I implemented an action mode toolbar that allows me to delete multiple items in my recyclerView. I have a list of integer of all selected item index. So I would like to know what is the better way to perform my request.

Currently, when I try to remove 3 items, I have an error: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionNoteListViewHolder`

---

This is my code:

```
     private void deleteNote() {
        List<Note> temp = new ArrayList<>(notes);
        List<Integer> selectedItems = noteListAdapter.getSelectedItems();

        notes.removeAll(selectedItems.stream().map(notes::get).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        for (int notes_index: selectedItems) {
            noteListAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(notes_index);
        }

        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make("test").setAction("ANNULER", v1 -> {
            // reinsert the note if undo action
            for (int index: selectedItems) {
                notes.add(index, temp.get(index));
                noteListAdapter.notifyItemInserted(index);
            }
        });

        snackbar.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Few options here, you could change your code to instead of calling `removeAll`, to remove one by one calling `notifyItemRemoved` straight afterwards like you did when adding items and using `notifyItemInserted`.

You could also replace your for loop with `notifyItemRemoved` by a single call to `notifyDataSetChanged` but it's not an optimal solution. For better performance, you should look on using [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil?hl=sr).

Comment: DiffUtil seems complex to use, have you got an example code please ?

Comment: https://medium.com/@iammert/using-diffutil-in-android-recyclerview-bdca8e4fbb00